# Mapping property values between 2 entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Lets say i have 2 instances of my entities, A and B. I want to map each value from entity A over to entity B. At the moment im doing something similar to

```
A.firstprop = B.firstprop;
A.secondprop = B.secondprop;
```

etc.. Im not sure how to solve this in a loop, so i would like some assistance on that part. Thanks!

Comment: Check out `Clone` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: take a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2010/05/24/how-to-share-common-fields-between-two-entities-that-map-to-different-tables.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question : How to solve it in the loop  is like

```
        var e1 = new Entity();
        var e2 = // Get Entity 

        foreach (var p in e1.GetType().GetProperties())
        { 
            p.SetValue(e1 , e2.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name ).GetValue(e2 , null) , null );
        }
```

So that , you can copy the value from entity2 to entity1  by looping

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) library.  This will simplify having to write all of the mappings by hand.

Comment: Thanks but i would prefer a solution without another framework icluded.